# Guice - create binding to java.lang.class

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

Is there any slick way (if any) for Guice to somehow bind a class type to an interface? I don't mean an instance of the class, but the actual java.lang.class type itself.

i.e. (obviously doesn't work, but tells what I'm after):

```
bind(MyInterface.class).to(Class<MyImplementation>)
```

I know it doesn't seem possible on the outset, but I didn't know if there were any tricks I could take to do this. One that comes to mind would be wrapping the class type in an actual instantiated object or something, but that seems like a last resort.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not very clear for me. What do you want to inject ? May be you could tell us more about the use case. Give us an SSCCE, the `class`, `interface` source code and also the class which depends on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out after RTFM. I just missed the existence of the "toInstance" method:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral(Class<? extends MyInterface>)(){}).toInstance(MyImplementation.class)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into a similar issue!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want to do a normal binding

```
bind(MyInterface.class).to(MyImplementation.class)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking to bind to get the actual class as opposed to an instance of it. I figured it out and left the answer below.